Expected number of original items after some replacements
The problem is this: There are always 6 items on a shelf. Each week, two random items are purchased and two new items are added in their places. Suppose there is an infinite supply of items. What is the expected number of the initial items after week $n$?
I tried to calculate the first few cases and come up with a pattern. Let $X_n$ be the random variable: the original items left on the shelf after week $n$. Here $X_n$ ranges from 0 to 6.
Intially it's certain that $X_0 = 6$, or $\Pr(X_0=6) = 1$, while the other values are of probability zero.
After week 1, two of the items get replaced so $\Pr(X_1=4) = 1$, and we know for certain that there are 4 original items.
There are three cases for week 2: $X_2 \in \{4, 3 , 2\}$. In the first case, the two new items from the first week are replaced, so we still end up with 4 original items. So the probability is $\Pr(X_2=4) = \frac{2\choose2}{6\choose2} = \frac{1}{15}$.
In the second case, the two replaced items include one new and one original, so there are three original items left: $\Pr(X_2=3) = \frac{4\cdot2}{6\choose2} = \frac{8}{15}.$
In the third case, only two originals are left, since we proceed to replace two out of four of them: $\Pr(X_2=2) = \frac{4\choose2}{6\choose2} = \frac{6}{15}$. The expected value for this week is then worked out to be $2.\bar{6}$.
Week 3 is where it gets too complicated for me as there are too many cases to consider. I know that $X_3$ and so on can only range from 4 down to 0, but I still haven't come up with a pattern. Intuitively, $(X_n = 0)$ should become more and more likely as the weeks go on. It seems to me there is a more effective way to calculate this but it requires concepts I haven't learned.
After some searching, I come up with the seemingly related Coupon collector problem, but the point of that problem is to find the expected weeks until all original items are collected, and not the expected number of unreplaced items left after a certain week. Is there a connection between these two problems?

Maybe use conditional probabilities to come up with an iterative expression?

You must have some error in your week 2 calculations.  It should have come to $8/3$, not $7/3$ as you had found.

The first item will continue to be the original after $n$ weeks iff in all weeks only items different than the first are selected.  What is the chance it wasn't selected in week $1$?  In week $2$?  In week $n$?  All of these simultaneously?  Now, apply linearity of expectation.
More explicitly, let $X$ be the random variable counting the number of original items left, and let $X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots$ be the indicator random variables for whether or not item $1,2,3,\dots$ were still the original items at the end.  Notice that $X=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_6$ and that $E[X] = E[X_1+X_2+\dots+X_6] = E[X_1]+E[X_2]+\dots+E[X_6] = 6\cdot E[X_1]$ by linearity of expectation and symmetry.

 Item 1 fails to be selected in the first week with probability $\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{4}{5} = \frac{2}{3}$.  It fails to be selected throughout all weeks combined with probability $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$

$~$

 Applying linearity of expectation, we get an expected number of $6\cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ original items after $n$ weeks.

This of course matches the found results for $n=0$ (6 original), $n=1$ (4 original) and $n=2$ (8/3) as we expected it would.

Are you sure?  The way that I read the problem, random items are purchased every day, rather than once per week.  Assuming that the purchases occur $~7~$ days per week, the chance of a random item surviving for one week is then $~(2/3)^7.$

@user2661923 I did not read the post carefully enough, but it would seem that the OP made the same mistake in reading it.  I merely followed their reading and they say that with $n=1$ there are four remaining guaranteed, so they must have also mixed up the words "week" and "day".  If you want seven occurrences of pairs of things being bought and replaced per increase in $n$... simply replace $n$ in the above with $7n$.  Otherwise, it is a clear case of a typo and the OP meant to say "Each week, two random items..." instead of "Each day, two random items..."  The math otherwise doesn't change.

In fact, my guess is that your first interpretation is the one intended by the problem composer.  That is, what would be the point of having to further specify how many days per week that purchases are made?  Also, my instinct is that there is little educational value in burdening a new student with the complication of a survival rate per week being $~(2/3)^7~$ rather than $~(2/3).$

Thanks for the answer @JMoravitz. I did mix up days and weeks as a typo.

After all, it is $n$ - the number of replacements that matters here.
